# Excel Use of SUMPRODUCT to multiply column then reduce percentage column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumproduct

Update: I've got the formula to work but now get a warning that the formula in the cell refers to cells that are currently empty, can someone help with that?
The formula now is:

=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A2,B1:B2,1-C1:C4%)

I'm sure this is a simple one, but I can't fathom it

I'm trying to multiply the rows of one column, with the corresponding values in another. That part I've got, what I need to do now is reduce this value by the percentage in another column.

Here's the dataset

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 5 | 10 |
| 5 | 6 | 8 |
| Total |  |  |

What I have so far for the Total is this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A2,B1:B2)*1-C1:C4
```

Which isn't working

COLUMN C is the percentage column

The total is the value of the formula I'm trying to create

Hope this makes sense

Comment: Hi Scott, that was quick but I get a weird number. As it always happens I've been looking at this for ages and just as I admit failure and add this question here I get the right the value =SUMPRODUCT(A1:A2, B1:B2, 1-C1:C2%) but I now get a value error as there are blanks in the percent column C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the column C range inside the SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A2,B1:B2,(1-C1:C2))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, that was quick but I get a weird number. As it always happens I've been looking at this for ages and just as I admit failure and add this question here I get the right the value =SUMPRODUCT(A1:A2, B1:B2, 1-C1:C2%) but I now get a value error as there are blanks in the percent column C

Comment: Then you need to add to the formula to deal with the blanks.